# Calling a model function in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

is there any method I can call a model function in admin.py for eg suppose I have a model say

```
class A(models.Model):
    first = models.IntegerField()
    second = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()

    def Total_amount(self):
        self.total+=first
        self.total+=second
```

Now I want that whenever I do something from admin side into first and second it automatically must reflect into total's value.How can I do that I mean I can do something in ModelAdmin class but its not working from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a model in the admin, it calls the full_clean method on your model's instance. I suggest you override the clean() method on that model to get the behavior you want, e.g.:

```
def clean(self):
    super(MyModel, self).clean()
    self.Total_amount()
```